# Is there a specific reason for not being able to assign values in 2D vector unlike of 1D vector

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, variable-assignment, 2d-vector

I understand that we can insert values in 2D vector as  `vec[i].push_back(value)` but I was trying to insert value in the 2D vector as  `vec[i][j] = value` , but it was giving the error :

*Line 1034: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator>' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/../../../../include/c++/9/bits/stl_vector.h:1043:9*

Ideally when we use a 1D vector we can assign values like  `a[i] = value` . But in 2D vectors why does C++ not allow assignment of values in 2D vector like this.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    vector<vector<int>> v;
    int i,j,n = 3,m = 4,num;
    for(i=0;i < n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            cin>>num;
            v[i][j] = num;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i < n;i++){
        for(j=0;j<m;j++){
            cout<<v[i][j]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }
}
```

If it was a 2D array. We could do this operaion. But, why not in a vector. Can you please refer me a material to read about it ?

Comment: It does, but you haven’t shown the full code. Most likely you haven’t allocated the memory for the vectors so it catches the problem for you.

Comment: It's not clear if you understand the difference between `std::vector::pushback` and `std::vector::operator[]`.

Comment: You can do that in a vector of vectors just like you can for a vector with the same proviso - that the element already exists. `=` for a vector does not insert an item, it changes the value of an existing one. `push_back` is different, as it appends a new entry and sets its value.

Comment: you should post a [mcve]. My crystal ball tells me that you properly resized the 1d vector but not the 2d vector. Perhaps you resized the first dimension to have a vector with N elments and those elements are empty vectors, such that for any `j` this is out of bounds: `vec[i][j]`. The trick is to understand that there is no difference between a vector and a vector that is an element of another vector

Comment: I have added the example code where, it gives error.

Comment: You never add any elements to any of your vectors. They are all empty vectors and all your v[i][j] reverences are invalid. Size your vectors to the desired size first - or push back entries as needed.

Comment: Move your definition of v down to after you establish n & m with values and the change the definition to `vector<vector<int>> v( n, vector<int>(m) );` to start with a 3x4 rather than a 0x0 vector of vectors. Or start with 0x0 as you are and use push_back to add entries.